# How to initialize z object to use z.JSON.parse function in a code Zap?

Tags: javascript, json, google-calendar-api, zapier

I'm developing a Zapier zap. The source is Google calendar. I collect the event description. It is a json string. I want to turn it into an object to process it in a Zap code (in JavaScript). The doc recommends to use the `z.JSON.parse()` function. I do it but at run time the error `z is not initialized` is sent. How to JSON parse a string to make an object ?

I tried to add `z = new Z()`, but it didn't work.

```
var eventDescriptorString = {
    codeEvt: 'ID-LGC-02/21/2019-testoon_mail',
    appCible: 'SIB',
    action: 'testoon_mail',
    parametre: 'ID-LGC-02/21/2019-testoon_mail-presents'
}
var eventDescriptorObject = z.JSON.parse(inputData.eventDescriptorString);
console.log('action', eventDescriptorObject.action);
output = [{
    'action': eventDescriptorObject.action
}];
```

I expect action to equal `'testoon_mail'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

The docs you found are probably for the app scripting environment. While similar, it's got access to a separate set of functions (and the `z` object itself). Code steps (which is what you're using here) are "plain" javascript environments.

If you change `z.JSON.parse` -> `JSON.parse` it should work as expected.